# Trying to pull down a remote branch that has been deleted locally

Tags: git, branch, pull

I created a branch in git and pushed it to the remote.  I then deleted it locally. Now, I want to pull it again so I can work on it locally and make changes.  However, when I try to pull it from the remote, it says 'already up-to-date' and I do not see it locally.  Can I not pull it anymore because I deleted it once?  How can I get it locally again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checkout the branch `git checkout branch-name`